# Google Glass Home Icons Gone Missing

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

On XE18 non approved glassware in testing no longer display their icons. I've compared the manifests of approved apps to mine and not identified any difference.

Has anyone encountered this and found a solution?

Comment: This did not happen to my apps after the update. The update might be a red herring in your case.

Comment: I'm on 18.3 and I had a similar experience. On 16 it worked fine, I upgraded this morning and they stopped appearing.

Comment: Yes, same problem here also...and 18.3 is getting hot quickely

Comment: Jacob, after the update and this problem was noticed, my Glass was replaced.  I received in XE17.11, where I immediately sideloaded my and several other unapproved glassware apks. For all of these apps, the icons displayed normally, after the XE18 update later that afternoon, The same apks were installed and now suddenly these app icons no longer displayed

Comment: FYI. There is an issue open on Google Code and accepted by the Google Glass team: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=559&q=icon&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary

Comment: Yup thanks I'm in that thread too!

Comment: It's fixed! They will push it out with next ota update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments and by EntryLevelDev, the OTA update XE19.1 has pushed out a fix to this bug.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed on XE19.1.

Just for reference, info is [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=559) as mentioned in comments.

Cheers!

Comment: oh right, didn't see it. You can answer your own question and accept it. :)